# Why aren't my divs horizontally aligned?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to horizontally align three `div`s that are inside a bigger `div`, here is my code:

```css
#creators {
  text-align: center;
}
.creator_name {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 1% 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="about" class="big-part">
  <h3>About us</h3>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div id="work" class="big-part">
  <h3>Work</h3>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div id="creators" class="big-part">
  <h3>Creators</h3>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried with `float: left` but the webpage becomes glitchy.
with float left:[image: result]
Any help is welcomed, thanks!

Comment: Is this not good ? https://jsfiddle.net/bz1yyq19/

Comment: Are you trying to display them in a horizontal line?

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE! You guys answered so quickly!

Comment: @FilpFloop Sorry about the fiddles, the demo is on a snippet now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

Sorry about the fiddles, there must be a limit on free accounts. Anyways I placed the demo in a snippet.

Looks like I made the first demo too quick and made a different layout than the one you wanted, my bad. Here's a layout that builds on the first one, basically I made `#siteNav` `flex` `column`.

**Column Layout**

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* Core CSS */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.45'Source Code Pro';
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}
body {
  background: #121;
  color: #FEF;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#siteNav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
#creators {
  text-align: center;
}
.creator_name {
  width: 31%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.big-part {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
#about,
#work,
#creators {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="siteNav">
  <section id="about" class="big-part">
    <h3>About us</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </section>

  <section id="work" class="big-part">
    <h3>Work</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </section>

  <section id="creators" class="big-part">
    <h3>Creators</h3>
    <div class="creator_name">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="creator_name">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="creator_name">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</nav>
```

---

---

## Changes

- I agree, `floats` are evil.
- Wrapped everything in a `<nav>`
- Added CSS defaults to even out any inconsistencies from browser defaults.
- Set `<nav>` `display: table` `table-layout: fixed` `border-collapse`. Now `#siteNav` is a table in all but name.
- Then `#about`, `#work`, and `#creators` to `display: table-cell`
- Made each `.big-part` a `<section>` so they're easier to see in markup.
- The 3 separate blocks of content in `#creators` are `display: inline-block`
- It goes without saying, this layout is responsive.

---

**Width Ratios**

First Level `#siteNav 100%`

`#about 20% / #work 20% / #creators 60%`

Second Level `#creators 60%`

`.creator_name 31% x 3 = 93%`

---

**Row Layout**

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* Core CSS */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.45'Source Code Pro';
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}
body {
  background: #121;
  color: #FEF;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#siteNav {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
#creators {
  text-align: center;
}
.creator_name {
  width: 31%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.big-part {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
#about,
#work {
  width: 20%;
}
#creators {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="siteNav">
  <section id="about" class="big-part">
    <h3>About us</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </section>

  <section id="work" class="big-part">
    <h3>Work</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
  </section>

  <section id="creators" class="big-part">
    <h3>Creators</h3>
    <div class="creator_name">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="creator_name">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="creator_name">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: No problem, I noticed you unaccepted this answer, is it not what you wanted? If your'e looking for something let me know whenever. :)

Comment: Oh, ok thanks @FlipFloop well if you still have any problems let me know. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `display: inline-block` on `creator_name`

```
.creator_name {
    width: 22%;
    margin: 1% 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: inline-block;` coupled with `vertical-align: top;` and `margin-left: -4px;` to align the divs in the big div.

```css
#creators {
  text-align: center;
}
.creator_name {
  width: 30.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*
   * Used to fight white space between divs
   * https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
   */
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin: 1% 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="about" class="big-part">
  <h3>About us</h3>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div id="work" class="big-part">
  <h3>Work</h3>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div id="creators" class="big-part">
  <h3>Creators</h3>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information on the `margin-left: -4px;` see: [Fighting the space between inline block elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Thanks for the article, it's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to clear floats if you use them. The simple way to do so is to use overflow: auto on the parent container:

```css
#creators {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
.creator_name {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 1% 1%;
  float: left;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="creators" class="big-part">
  <h3>Creators</h3>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are tying to center align them. Use css flex.

Put all 3 divs in a wrapper div. Then give the wrapper div `display:flex;justify-content:center;` CSS properties.

```css
.wrapper{display:flex;justify-content:center;}
.inner{background:#f2f5f6;margin: 0 1em 0;border:solid 1px #ffcc00;padding:.25em;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">One</div>
  <div class="inner">Two</div>
  <div class="inner">Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Your code was almost there just needed some more CSS.

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
#about, #work {
  background: #7D26CD;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
#creators {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.creator_name {
   width: 31%;
   margin: 1% 1%;
   float: left;
   display: inline-block;
}

.big-part {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "about" class = "big-part">
    <h3>About us</h3>
    <p>Text</p>

</div>

<div id = "work" class = "big-part">
    <h3>Work</h3>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div id = "creators" class = "big-part">
    <h3>Creators</h3>
    <div class = "creator_name">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>

    <div class = "creator_name">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>

    <div class = "creator_name">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because by default div's are `display: block;`.

```css
#creators {
  text-align: center;
}
.creator_name {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 1% 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="about" class="big-part">
  <h3>About us</h3>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div id="work" class="big-part">
  <h3>Work</h3>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div id="creators" class="big-part">
  <h3>Creators</h3>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to your `.creator_name` rule. This will stop the`divs` from automatically occupying the entire width and not allowing any other elements on the same line. Here's a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/8hLodkup/.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why don't use float:left, i have make the same example with float:left and work.
Look:
**html**

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="tree">
            <ul id="ulroot">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="file">
            <ul id="ulfile"></ul>
        </div>  
            <div id="detail"></div> </div>
```

**css**

```
#content{
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
border: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
background-color: #80FF80;
display:block}

#tree{
float:left;
height: 100%;
min-height:100%;
width: 30%; }
#file{
float:left;
height: 100%;
width: 30%;}
#detail{
float:left;
height: 100%;
min-height:100%;
width: 40%;}
```